# Background Job Status from Gearman

Tags: python, jobs, gearman

I have a web-based script which creates a background job (executes SSH commands) in Gearman, this is successful. However when I try to retrieve the status of the job in subsequent web requests I am unable too.

My job creation looks similar too:

```
import gearman

gm  = gearman.GearmanClient( ['127.0.0.1'] )
job = gm.submit_job( 'ssh_execute', 'shell-command', background = True )
```

and from this I can get the job `handle` and `unique` ID and these are passed between requests. This is successful and the job completes.

From googling and stack overflow the recommendation to get a job's status is:

```
import gearman

gm  = gearman.GearmanClient( ['127.0.0.1'] )
job = gearman.job.GearmanJob( gm, 'handle', 'ssh_execute', 'unqiue id', None )
req = gearman.job.GearmanJobRequest( job )
```

However this fails, and is unable to retrieve any information about the job (i.e. the state is always `UNKNOWN`). Example object from `job` and `req`:

```
<GearmanJob connection/handle=(<gearman.client.GearmanClient object at 0x10f42db50>, 'H:proxy:1'), task=ssh_execute, unique=ce96e33721d5f3ef5394502b8c6621fa, data=None>
<GearmanJobRequest task='ssh_execute', unique='ce96e33721d5f3ef5394502b8c6621fa', priority=None, background=True, state='UNKNOWN', timed_out=False>
```

I am using the [Yelp Gearman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gearman/) library and `gearman-job-server` 0.27 on Ubuntu 12.04.